# Is it possible to create a key binding which executes multiple commands in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am looking for a way to ensure that I can have a single key binding execute multiple commands. I do not see anything within the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) which suggests that this is possible; However, I figured I'd check here to see if there is a work around, or something not captured within the docs. I have tried multiple things:

This hasn't produced the expected result, despite being correct syntax (it only executes the first command).

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+t",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+t",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel"
},
```

And this is invalid syntax (along with commands within the same string that are space or `,` delimited.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+t",
    "command": [
        "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
        "workbench.action.toggleMaximizedPanel"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Have a look at macros like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command (multi-command)

Comment: @Mark that worked perfectly, thank you!